# How to know the current file which is being read when using Heka (mozilla) with logstreamer for sequential files

Tags: firefox

In Heka we can use the logstreamer to read sequential log files (e.g. `access.log`, `access.log.0`, `access.log.1`, etc.) using something like this.

```
[accesslogs]
type = "LogstreamerInput"
log_directory = "/var/log/nginx"
file_match = 'access\.log\.?(?P<Seq>\d*)'
priority = ["^Seq"]
```

Any idea on how to know which file is being read at a given time? Is there a way to get the file name to the decoder or do I have to write a customer input plugin?

Any insight is much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for knowing the current file, you should be able to look at the journal file in the [journal_directory](https://hekad.readthedocs.org/en/v0.10.0b1/config/inputs/logstreamer.html). For me, that default was /var/cache/hekad/logstreamer/< heka input name >.